# Convert mathematical notation to string

Tags: r, tostring

The solution might be very simply, but I can't seem to figure it out easily. I have the following number:

```
a = 1000000
#> a
#[1] 1e+06
```

I would like to convert "a" to a string, but when I try using `toString`, it gives the following:

```
#> toString(a)
#[1] "1e+06"
```

I would like to get: 1,000,000 instead, **with the comma separator**. Is that easily feasible?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `prettyNum`

Comment: Have a look at [`sprintf`](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Strings/Creating_strings_from_variables/). In your case you can do `sprintf("%i", a)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`format(1e6, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)` or  `prettyNum(1000000,big.mark=",",scientific=F)` should give you the desired result

Comment: Since it's just text, why not `paste`?